# Is there a direct way of adding two random step size lists

Tags: core-language

As shown in the figure, I have three lists a,b and c. I want to see whether `a + b +C0= c`(here C0 is a constant).

Since list a and b have varing step size (automatic increament size) and result in different length, as best I can do is fit the two lists `a` and `b` before adding them to compare with list `c`.

I wonder is there a direct (functional) way of adding two lists like that in Mathematica?

[image]

Thanks Hugh, I got the check through the function Interpolation as the following codes. The "pl2" is shown in the second figure, and the error "errorPlot" is shown in the third figure.

```
a = {{0., 20.}, {1., 20.0004}, {2., 20.0012}, {3., 20.0023}, {5., 
20.0054}, {9., 20.0123}, {17., 20.0266}, {33., 20.0552}, {65., 
20.1121}, {129., 20.2244}, {257., 20.443}, {385., 20.6558}, {513.,
 20.863}, {759.799, 21.2426}, {1006.6, 21.6032}, {1253.4, 
21.946}, {1500.2, 22.2716}, {1747., 22.5811}, {1993.79, 
22.8751}, {2240.59, 23.1545}, {2487.39, 23.42}, {2734.19, 
23.6723}, {2980.99, 23.912}, {3227.79, 24.1398}, {3474.59, 
24.3562}, {3721.39, 24.5619}, {4200.75, 24.9245}, {4680.11, 
25.2535}, {5159.47, 25.5522}, {5638.83, 25.8233}, {6118.19, 
26.0694}, {6597.55, 26.2927}, {7076.91, 26.4954}, {8021.6, 
26.8281}, {8966.28, 27.1053}, {9910.96, 27.3361}, {10855.6, 
27.5284}, {12745., 27.8029}, {14634.4, 27.9988}, {16523.7, 
28.1386}, {18523.7, 28.2425}, {20523.7, 28.3155}, {22523.7, 
28.3667}, {24523.7, 28.4026}, {26523.7, 28.4278}, {28523.7, 
28.4455}, {30523.7, 28.458}, {32523.7, 28.4667}, {34523.8, 
28.4728}, {36523.8, 28.4771}, {38523.8, 28.4801}, {40523.8, 
28.4823}, {42523.8, 28.4837}, {44523.8, 28.4848}, {46523.8, 
28.4855}, {48523.8, 28.486}, {50523.8, 28.4864}, {52523.8, 
28.4866}, {54523.8, 28.4868}, {56523.8, 28.4869}, {58523.8, 
28.487}, {60523.8, 28.4871}, {62523.8, 28.4871}, {64523.8, 
28.4872}, {66523.8, 28.4872}, {68523.8, 28.4872}, {70523.8, 
28.4872}, {72523.8, 28.4872}, {74523.8, 28.4872}};
b = {{0., 20.}, {1., 20.0011}, {2., 20.0035}, {3., 20.007}, {5., 
20.0162}, {9., 20.037}, {17., 20.0798}, {33., 20.1657}, {65., 
20.3364}, {129., 20.6732}, {193., 21.0055}, {257., 
21.3333}, {321., 21.6568}, {385., 21.9759}, {449., 
22.2907}, {513., 22.6013}, {577., 22.9077}, {641., 23.21}, {705., 
23.5083}, {769., 23.8026}, {833., 24.0929}, {897., 
24.3794}, {961., 24.662}, {1025., 24.9408}, {1089., 
25.2159}, {1153., 25.4873}, {1217., 25.755}, {1281., 
26.0192}, {1345., 26.2798}, {1409., 26.5369}, {1473., 
26.7906}, {1537., 27.0409}, {1601., 27.2878}, {1665., 
27.5314}, {1729., 27.7718}, {1793., 28.0089}, {1857., 
28.2429}, {1921., 28.4737}, {1985., 28.7014}, {2049., 
28.9261}, {2113., 29.1477}, {2177., 29.3664}, {2241., 
29.5822}, {2305., 29.795}, {2369., 30.005}, {2490.74, 
30.3944}, {2612.47, 30.774}, {2734.21, 31.144}, {2855.95, 
31.5047}, {2977.69, 31.8564}, {3099.42, 32.1991}, {3221.16, 
32.5333}, {3342.9, 32.859}, {3464.64, 33.1765}, {3586.37, 
33.486}, {3708.11, 33.7877}, {3829.85, 34.0818}, {3951.59, 
34.3685}, {4073.32, 34.6479}, {4195.06, 34.9204}, {4316.8, 
35.1859}, {4438.54, 35.4448}, {4560.27, 35.6972}, {4682.01, 
35.9432}, {4803.75, 36.183}, {4925.49, 36.4167}, {5047.22, 
36.6446}, {5168.96, 36.8667}, {5290.7, 37.0833}, {5412.44, 
37.2944}, {5534.17, 37.5001}, {5770.51, 37.8805}, {6006.86, 
38.2427}, {6243.2, 38.5876}, {6479.54, 38.916}, {6715.88, 
39.2288}, {6952.22, 39.5266}, {7188.57, 39.8101}, {7424.91, 
40.0801}, {7661.25, 40.3372}, {7897.59, 40.5821}, {8133.93, 
40.8152}, {8370.27, 41.0372}, {8606.62, 41.2486}, {8842.96, 
41.4499}, {9311.98, 41.8132}, {9781.01, 42.1436}, {10250., 
42.444}, {10719.1, 42.7173}, {11188.1, 42.9658}, {11657.1, 
43.1918}, {12126.1, 43.3974}, {13037.7, 43.7321}, {13949.2, 
44.0125}, {14860.7, 44.2475}, {15772.2, 44.4444}, {17595.2, 
44.7282}, {19418.3, 44.9329}, {21241.3, 45.0805}, {23241.3, 
45.1941}, {25241.3, 45.2739}, {27241.3, 45.3298}, {29241.3, 
45.3692}, {31241.3, 45.3967}, {33241.3, 45.4161}, {35241.3, 
45.4297}, {37241.3, 45.4392}, {39241.3, 45.4459}, {41241.3, 
45.4506}};
c = {{0., 20.}, {1., 20.0014}, {2., 20.0046}, {3., 20.0093}, {5., 
20.0216}, {9., 20.0493}, {17., 20.1065}, {33., 20.221}, {65., 
20.4486}, {97., 20.6746}, {129., 20.8991}, {161., 21.1221}, {193.,
 21.3436}, {225., 21.5636}, {257., 21.7822}, {289., 
21.9992}, {321., 22.2148}, {353., 22.4289}, {385., 
22.6416}, {417., 22.8529}, {449., 23.0627}, {509.922, 
23.457}, {570.844, 23.8464}, {631.766, 24.2307}, {692.689, 
24.6102}, {753.611, 24.9848}, {814.533, 25.3546}, {875.455, 
25.7197}, {936.377, 26.0802}, {997.299, 26.436}, {1058.22, 
26.7873}, {1119.14, 27.1341}, {1180.07, 27.4765}, {1240.99, 
27.8145}, {1301.91, 28.1482}, {1362.83, 28.4776}, {1423.75, 
28.8028}, {1484.68, 29.1239}, {1545.6, 29.4409}, {1606.52, 
29.7538}, {1667.44, 30.0627}, {1728.37, 30.3677}, {1789.29, 
30.6688}, {1850.21, 30.9661}, {1911.13, 31.2595}, {1972.05, 
31.5492}, {2032.98, 31.8352}, {2093.9, 32.1176}, {2154.82, 
32.3963}, {2215.74, 32.6715}, {2276.66, 32.9432}, {2337.59, 
33.2114}, {2398.51, 33.4762}, {2459.43, 33.7376}, {2520.35, 
33.9957}, {2581.28, 34.2504}, {2642.2, 34.5019}, {2703.12, 
34.7502}, {2764.04, 34.9954}, {2824.96, 35.2374}, {2885.89, 
35.4763}, {2946.81, 35.7122}, {3007.73, 35.945}, {3068.65, 
36.1749}, {3129.58, 36.4018}, {3190.5, 36.6259}, {3251.42, 
36.8471}, {3312.34, 37.0654}, {3373.26, 37.281}, {3434.19, 
37.4938}, {3495.11, 37.7039}, {3610.94, 38.0938}, {3726.77, 
38.4743}, {3842.6, 38.8457}, {3958.43, 39.2082}, {4074.26, 
39.562}, {4190.09, 39.9073}, {4305.92, 40.2443}, {4421.75, 
40.5732}, {4537.58, 40.8942}, {4653.41, 41.2075}, {4769.24, 
41.5133}, {4885.07, 41.8117}, {5000.9, 42.103}, {5116.72, 
42.3873}, {5232.56, 42.6648}, {5348.38, 42.9356}, {5464.21, 
43.2}, {5580.04, 43.4579}, {5695.87, 43.7097}, {5811.7, 
43.9554}, {5927.53, 44.1953}, {6043.36, 44.4294}, {6159.19, 
44.6578}, {6275.02, 44.8808}, {6390.85, 45.0985}, {6506.68, 
45.3109}, {6622.51, 45.5182}, {6845.7, 45.8996}, {7068.89, 
46.2637}, {7292.08, 46.6114}, {7515.27, 46.9433}, {7738.46, 
47.2603}, {7961.65, 47.5628}, {8184.84, 47.8517}, {8408.03, 
48.1276}, {8631.22, 48.3909}, {8854.41, 48.6424}, {9077.6, 
48.8824}, {9300.79, 49.1116}, {9523.97, 49.3305}, {9747.16, 
49.5394}, {10173.9, 49.9057}, {10600.6, 50.2415}, {11027.3, 
50.5495}, {11454., 50.8319}, {11880.8, 51.0908}, {12307.5, 
51.3282}, {12734.2, 51.5459}, {13160.9, 51.7455}, {14014.4, 
52.0835}, {14867.8, 52.3696}, {15721.3, 52.6119}, {16574.7, 
52.817}, {18237., 53.1123}, {19899.3, 53.3305}, {21561.5, 
53.4918}, {23561.5, 53.6281}, {25561.5, 53.7237}, {27561.5, 
53.7908}};
C0 = 20;
ff1 = Interpolation[a];
ff2 = Interpolation[b];
ff3 = Interpolation[c];
ffInterP = Plot[(ff1[x] + ff2[x] - C0), {x, 1, 30000}, PlotLegends -> {"Interpolation of a+b-C0"}];
listPlot = ListPlot[{a, b, c}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Black}, PlotRange -> {{1, 4000}, {5, 25}}, PlotLegends -> {"a", "b", "c"}]; 
pl2 = Show[ffInterP, listPlot]
errorPlot =  Plot[ff1[x] + ff2[x] - C0 - ff3[x], {x, 1, 30000}, PlotLegends -> {"Error of: Interpolation of a+b-C0-c"}]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I suggest you use interpolation to turn the list into a function and then check your hypothesis. Look up `Interpolation` . If you post the data points in mathematica form I will give you an example.

Comment: The question is underspecified.  Would you be satisfied to make the comparison only for values where all (`a`, `b`, `c`) exist?  If not, what notion of equality do you wish to use?  (E.g., approximate equality after some kind of interpolation?)

Comment: Before your question can be answered, the concepts you entertain concerning the sum of two lists and the equality of the sum to a third list must be made precise.

Comment: Thanks Hugh, I got the check through Interpolation!

Comment: Glad to see it helped. I would also suggest doing a subtraction to see the size of the error, i.e. `a+b-c0 -c`.

Comment: Hi, Hugh. I gave the data and error! Thanks for suggestion and inspiration.